# Insert 1D array into 2D array spots

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to insert a 1 dimensional array into each spot inside a 2 dimensional array. 
Example of what I am trying to do:

```
int[][] Array2D = new int[3][3];
int[] Array1D = {0, 0, 0};
```

So my 2D Array will theoretically look like this:

```
int[][] Array2D = 
{x, x, x,
 x, x, x,
 x ,x, x};
```

And I am trying to insert my Array1D into each x spot like so:

```
int[][] Array2D = 
{0 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 0,
 0 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 0,
 0 0 0 ,0 0 0, 0 0 0};

for (int x = 0; x < Array2D.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Array2D.length; y++) {
            Array2D[x][y] = Array1D;
            System.out.print(Canvas[x][y]+" ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description and code, you are trying to assign the 1-D array to a 3-D array. Therefore you should declare the arrays as :

```
int[][][] Array3D = new int[3][3][];
int[] Array1D = {0, 0, 0};

for (int x = 0; x < Array3D.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < Array3D[0].length; y++) {
        Array3D[x][y] = Array1D;
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Array3D[x][y])+" ");
    }
}
```